# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, android-sqlite

These are  the stack traces I got from Developer console:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: cannot rollback - no transaction is active (code 1)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:555)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransactionUnchecked(SQLiteSession.java:439)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:401)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:522)
at android.webkit.WebViewDatabaseClassic.initDatabase(WebViewDatabaseClassic.java:165)
at android.webkit.WebViewDatabaseClassic.init(WebViewDatabaseClassic.java:130)
at android.webkit.WebViewDatabaseClassic.access$000(WebViewDatabaseClassic.java:35)
at android.webkit.WebViewDatabaseClassic$1.run(WebViewDatabaseClassic.java:109)
```

And one more:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: formurl: , while compiling: SELECT _id FROM formurl WHERE (url == ?)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1686)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1571)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1527)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1607)
at android.webkit.WebViewDatabase.getFormData(WebViewDatabase.java:1212)
at android.webkit.WebView$RequestFormData.run(WebView.java:7764)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I use WebView in one of my screens. Here are my webview settings:

```
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        webView.clearCache(true);
        deleteDatabase("webview.db");
        deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db");
```

I set WebChromeClient and WebViewClient like this:

```
      webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,
                JsResult result) {
            return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onJsPrompt(WebView view, String url, String message,
                String defaultValue, JsPromptResult result) {
            return super.onJsPrompt(view, url, message, defaultValue,
                    result);
        }

    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            //My code to show progress bar

        }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;


    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           //My code to hide progress bar


    }
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl) {


    }

});
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: can you please post deleteDatabase() code ?

Comment: deleteDatabase is not method in app. It's from SDK itself

Comment: boolean android.content.ContextWrapper.deleteDatabase(String name)

Comment: @SeshuVinay did you resolve issue? please post here, i m also having same issue in HTC devices-4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this and see

```
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/pkgname/databases/");
```

Read here for more info 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html

Comment: I don't want WebView to use Dom Storage.

Comment: This webview is used for payment gateways. So I don't want to cache or store anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it -

```
context.deleteDatabase("webview.db");
context.deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db");
webView.clearCache(true);
```

and you know how to get the context of the Activity.

PS - you may want to check your app using only `webview.clearCache(true);` 

because I assume that it automatically deletes `webView.db/webviewCache.db`. So no need after `webView.clearCache(true);`